# How to configure src/main/java into another folder in spring boot (maven)

Tags: java, spring, database, maven, intellij-idea

I want to create a spring boot project (maven) in IntelliJ. However i want to move src/main/java or java source code into a folder called "backend" (located at root directory of the project. To elaborate more, there will be 3 folder at root directory called "frontend", "backend" and "db".

This project has establish connection with postgreSQL successfully. But when i move my src/main/java into another folder, it stated the error" cant find jpa.spring.datasource.url".

Comment: What is a error? Who knows may be it doesn't exist.

Comment: No you don't. You want 3 projects `frontend`, `backend` and `db` where `backend` depends on `db` and `frontend` (I assume) on `backend`. Each of these will have a `src/main/java`  in them (and `/src/main/resources`) as necessary. Don't mess around with the locations of the sources, it will bring you more trouble then it solves.

Comment: Maven has very strong opinions about how to do things.  There is a lot of pain and misery ahead if you don’t learn and obey 

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Michael Williams,

there is a very well established method in maven to do that properly.

You need 4 `pom.xml`:

```
project/pom.xml
project/backend/pom.xml
project/frontend/pom.xml
project/db/pom.xml
```

The first `project/pom.xml` may contain this `xml`:

```
<project> ...
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>backend</module>
    <module>frontend</module>
    <module>db</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

Would you concider this as an approach?

Answer (score 0):

In Practical, there should be separate project atleast for UI and backend. The database will be part of backend project.
Thats where Maven comes with folders to create the backend code in src/main/java and its test cases under src/test/java.
If still you want all the things to be under one project, go for modules.